# I keep getting IndexOutOfBounds error when I try to split a line from a file

Tags: java, string, split, indexoutofboundsexception

Well first of all hello! I am trying to read a file line by line and split that line in such a way that I can use the resulted substrings as params' for specific functions. I know it fails when it reaches "Min units consumed:". I tried to fix parts (first image below) as null also but it doesn't work. I am aware of the error but I don't know how to fix it alternatively. Some help would be awesome, cheers!

[image]

[image]

Comment: What are you trying to split the string at?

Comment: Please don’t post pictures of text. Copy and paste the text into your question. If you need help formatting, I’m sure someone will clean it up for you.

Comment: @Joe I split the string at { : } and a space after it cause' I want to get a clean string for the second part.. something like parts[1] = "Lights" and not parts[1] = " Lights" or ": Lights"

Comment: @IanMacDonald I didn't know that. sorry xD

Comment: You should check the length of array before accessing its elements. With your exception it seems like your line does not contain `: ` due to which your parts array is of length less than 2 resulting in error when you try to access `parts[1]` Can you print the line before splitting and also print array length?

Comment: @PushpeshKumarRajwanshi Yes I am aware of that..i know it crashes when for the line "Min units consumed:" because I have nothing after {:}. But I don't have any idea how to solve using another approach and get a clean string for the first part and a clean string for the second part.

Comment: Is it okey if i do something like if( currentLine.contains(": ")) and then compute the split method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although you should debug your code to find what your `parts` array is carrying inside, but to avoid getting IndexOutofBoundException, you should write code in a safer way, somewhat like this,

```
    System.out.println("currentLine: " + currentLine); // print the contents of currentLine too
    parts = currentLine.split(": ");
    if (parts.length >= 2) {
        System.out.println(parts[0] + " " + parts[1]);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Do this

```
String[] split = currentLine.split(":");
for (int i = 0; i < split.length; i++)
    split[i] = split[i].replaceFirst(" ", "").trim();
```